# Another Fourier transformation but with a $\sqrt{\mathbf{q}^2 + m^2}$ term now

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, feynman-diagrams, integration, mathematics

Just as the title proclaims, I have a Fourier transformation I am trying to determine. Here is the Fourier transformation in its full form:
\begin{equation}
\int\frac{d^3q}{(2\pi)^3}e^{i\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{r}}\left(\frac{\sqrt{4m^2+\mathbf{q}^2}\log(4m^2/(4m^2+\mathbf{q}^2))}{\mathbf{q}} - 2\right)\frac{a}{\mathbf{q}^5}
\end{equation}
where $a$ is some coefficient(not to worry about). It is suitable to assume that $m\geq0$ and $\mathbf{q}>0$. Here is my current attempt (negating the $-2$ component since I know how to handle $1/|\mathbf{q}|^{\alpha}$ Fourier transformations (see this post here: [Fourier transformation of log(q2)/q4 in d=3](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/791419/fourier-transformation-of-log-mathbfq2-mathbfq4-in-d-3)). Here is my current attempt (dropping the factor of $a$)
\begin{align}
\int\frac{d^3q}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{\left(\sqrt{4m^2+\mathbf{q}^2}\log(4m^2/(4m^2+\mathbf{q}^2))\right)}{\mathbf{q}^6}e^{i\mathbf{q}\cdot\mathbf{r}} & = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^3}\int_0^\infty dq\frac{\left(\sqrt{4m^2+q^2}\log(4m^2/(4m^2+q^2))\right)}{q^6}\cdot q^2\int_{-1}^1 d\cos(\theta) \int_0^{2\pi} d\phi e^{iqr\cos(\theta)}\\
& = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\int_0^\infty dq \frac{1}{iqr}{\frac{\sqrt{4m^2+q^2}\log(4m^2/(4m^2+q^2))}{q^4}}(e^{iqr} - e^{-iqr})\\
& = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^2}\int_0^\infty dq\:2i\sin(qr)\frac{1}{iqr}{\frac{\sqrt{4m^2+q^2}\log(4m^2/(4m^2+q^2))}{q^4}}\\
& = \frac{2}{(2\pi)^2r}\int_0^\infty dq\:{\frac{\sqrt{4m^2+q^2}\log(4m^2/(4m^2+q^2))}{q^5}}\sin(qr).
\end{align}
Now, the most obvious thing to do is to separate the $\log(x)$ into a constant part $\log(4m^2)$ and then into $-\log(4m^2 + q^2)$. This then appears to be similar to this post here: [Fourier transformation of $\log(q^2 + a^2)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2265386/). But, my main issue is the square root term which I tried to regularize via $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}$ which appears as
\begin{equation}
\sim -\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\int_0^\infty dq\: \frac{\sqrt{4m^2 + q^2 + \epsilon^2}\log(4m^2 + q^2)}{q^3}\frac{\sin(qr)}{q^2 + \epsilon^2}
\end{equation}
but Mathematica does not perform this integration and just throws it back out (since if it did the integration and $\epsilon$ term may be infinite but constant in only $\epsilon$ I can just throw it out for my purposes).

So my question is obviously HOW do I perform this integral, or what trick can I use? Or does anyone just have this integral sitting in an integral book?

(For anyone wondering, this is a term I found in Fourier transforming my QFT amplitude back to position space to get the potential out, hence the QFT tag).

Any suggestions on Mathematica usage or how to solve this are greatly appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: it looks like integration by parts may be useful to simplify things, but the poles of $1/q^5$ might ruin that.

EDIT(2): This is not a homework question nor a check my work question, I simply do not know the answer since it has come up in research... This is similar to another Fourier transform question I asked previously and that was not closed...

Comment: By substituting $q=2mk$, you can get rid of all the $4m^2$; you might want to redefine r to extract that out from the sine too. Then I would try to "complete the integral" of the logarithm, since it is already looking as $x\ln x$, and so on.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent let me try this, and then edit or answer my own question to see if it works, thanks.

Comment: Why is q boldfaced in the integrand? Do you mean $|\mathbf{q}| = q$ in every place, other than in $d^3 \mathbf{q} e^{- i \mathbf{q} \cdot \mathbf{r}}$?

Comment: @QuantumEyedea the boldface $\mathbf{q}$ is just meant to denote it is not 1-dimensional until we expand the integral in terms of its components i.e $(q,\theta,\phi)$ which in this case is just the momentum on a 2-sphere.

Answer (score 0):

So, I have been tackling this integral for awhile, and the main issue is the square root term that makes the integral highly divergent at $q\rightarrow \infty$. The way to get around this is to look at the integral in two different limits, $q^2\gg m^2$ and $q^2\ll m^2$ in where the first limit reduces to $\log((q^2+m^2)/m^2)-2$ and in the other limit becomes $q^2/6m^2$. In this manner, the integral now loses the square-root term, but depending on the power of the denominator, $|q|^{-\alpha}$. If the power of $\alpha>3$ then you need the following **two** regulartors:
\begin{equation}
\approx \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\int_0^\infty dq\:\sin(qr)\frac{\log(q^2+m^2)}{q^2+\epsilon^2}\frac{1}{q}e^{-q\epsilon}
\end{equation}
modulo some factor of $2\pi^2$ where the denominator regularizes the divergence found at $q\rightarrow 0$ while the exponential suppresses the divergence found when $q\rightarrow \infty$. This integral can be completed on Mathematica and then expand the answer using the series function via $\epsilon$ around $0$. This is how you can do really any integral of the $\log(q^2)/q^{\alpha}$.